# Importing Json to objects in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have been working trying to import a list of objects from Json to C#.

The Json structure is:

```
    "meta": {
        "file_version": 11,
        "machine_number": 210xxxxx,
        "software": {
            "software_date": "",
            "software_version": ""
        },
        "saved": {
            "user": "Bxxxxxx",
            "date": "20220810",
            "time": "132156"
        },
        "application": {
            "name": "Support",
            "type": "xxxxx_Support"
        },
        "validity": {
            "machine_model": "xxx",
            "arm_assembly": "xxx",
            "boom_pedestal": "xxx"
        }
    },
    "data": {
        "data532": {
            "number": 54,
            "name": "Abstützung vorne - zulässige vertikale Beinkraft (P1.Q1)",
            "format": 0,
            "digit": 0,
            "unit": 10,
            "category": 0,
            "min": 0,
            "max": 1000000,
            "value": 225000,
            "hexvalue": "0x00036EE8",
            "binvalue": "0b00000000000000110110111011101000"
        },
        "data533": {
            "number": 55,
            "name": "Abstützung vorne - zulässige vertikale Beinkraft (P1.Q2)",
            "format": 0,
            "digit": 0,
            "unit": 10,
            "category": 0,
            "min": 0,
            "max": 1000000,
            "value": 0,
            "hexvalue": "0x00000000",
            "binvalue": "0b00000000000000000000000000000000"
.
.
.
.
.
```

My problem is that I need to set up the objects DataXXX in C#.
Im trying with:

```
var dataconfig = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(jsonfile);
```

Where class Data is

```
        public class Data
        {

            public int number { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int format { get; set; }
            public int digit { get; set; }
            public int unit { get; set; }
            public int category { get; set; }
            public int min { get; set; }
            public int max { get; set; }
            public int value { get; set; }
            public string hexvalue { get; set; }
            public string binvalue { get; set; }

        }
```

But my dataXXX is inside another object called Data so the code is not working. And it's not a list also.

Comment: Maybe use a Dictionary<string,Data> as type for your "data" property

Answer (score 0):

In Newtonsoft.Json, there are two API's, one high-level (`JsonConvert`) and one low-level (Linq-to-Json). `JsonConvert` is great for parsing if the data matches the C# class structures you have. Linq-to-Json is great for custom processing and flexibility.

In your case, since your property names have numbers in them that you need to standardize to match C# classes, you probably need to use Linq-to-Json. This parses JSON into objects similar to a Dictionary. Here are the intro [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/queryinglinqtojson.htm).

Answer (score 0):

you should use Dictionary

```
public class Data {
  public Dictionary<string,DataModel> data {get; set;}
}
public class DataModel {
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int format { get; set; }
    public int digit { get; set; }
    public int unit { get; set; }
    public int category { get; set; }
    public int min { get; set; }
    public int max { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
    public string hexvalue { get; set; }
    public string binvalue { get; set; }
}
```

with Newtonsoft:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(jsonfile); //jsonfile must be includes data.
```

with System.Text.Json

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Data>(jsonfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only a data part, you can parse the json at first, after this you can deserialize any  part

```
var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(jsonFile);

Dictionary<string,Data> dataconfig = jsonParsed["data"].ToObject<Dictionary<string,Data>>();
```